# Combine multiple columns using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How do we combine two or more columns using dplyr?

```
df = data.frame(a=1:6, b=seq(2,6))
```

I need my output as

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
a 5
a 6
b 2
b 2
b 2
b 2
b 2
b 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:6, b = rep(2, 6))
df %>% mutate(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = as.numeric)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>%
  arrange(var)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert columns to numeric when they already are?

Comment: Yes your right both columns are already numeric and so you don't need to do the conversion. Sorry for the redundant code. However, if you have many columns to combine, then I think it might be safer to run that line to avoid potential errors!

Answer (score 0):

```
rev(stack(df))

   ind values
1    a      1
2    a      2
3    a      3
4    a      4
5    a      5
6    a      6
7    b      2
8    b      2
9    b      2
10   b      2
11   b      2
12   b      2
```